# which field in clang-format to define not to indent after preprocessor directive?

Tags: clang-format, preprocessor-directive

current codes after applying clang-format is:

```
#ifndef CEEDLING_TEST
static
#endif
    void
    Measurement(const uint16_t *buff)
{
    g_rmsValue1ms = Get1msRmsValue(buff);

    g_rmsValue60ms = MovingAvgFilter(&g_MaFilter, g_rmsValue1ms);
}
```

expected:

```
#ifndef CEEDLING_TEST
static
#endif
void Measurement(const uint16_t *buff)
{
    g_rmsValue1ms = Get1msRmsValue(buff);

    g_rmsValue60ms = MovingAvgFilter(&g_MaFilter, g_rmsValue1ms);
}
```

Does someone knows which parameter is used to define the behavior like that?

Comment: Would you please share your clang-format configuration (see option `--dump-config`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of the clang-format option for that.

I'd suggest a small change to your code. Instead of `#ifdef`-ing the `static` keyword, you could `#ifdef` a macro, that decides whether the function is static. This not only resolves issue with clang-format, but also potentially saves you a lot of `#ifdef CEEDLING_TEST`s and `#endif`s.

```
#ifdef CEEDLING_TEST
#define MY_STATIC
#else
#define MY_STATIC static
#endif

MY_STATIC
void Measurement(const uint16_t* buff)
{
    g_rmsValue1ms = Get1msRmsValue(buff);
    g_rmsValue60ms = MovingAvgFilter(&g_MaFilter, g_rmsValue1ms);
}
```

Comment: thank you and your workaround fix my problem. and I check my configuration of Clang-format that there is no option like --dump-config.

Comment: @Bryant If my answer fixed your problem, the best way of indicating that is by accepting my answer instead of writing a comment. :) Also, the `--dump-config` option is passed to `clang-format` from the command line. Like that `clang-format --dump-config`. If passed, it prints your complete configuration for formatting. This output is very useful when asking questions like yours. You can check what options are available with `clang-format --help`.